# how to start niagara station on different port using niagara console?

Tags: niagara-4

1. Currently we start station by the command station .
2. i would like to have two station running at the same time on port 4911 and 4912

Error shown is as below:

```
Administrator: Niagara Command Line - station n4energymanagodemo
    at javax.baja.util.Invocation.run(Invocation.java:47)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) 
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run( FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadRoolExecutor.runWbrker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadRoolExecutor$Wbrker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

INFO [10:04:14 06-Nov-19 GMT][javax.baja.web.BWebServer] Scheduling restart in 5 seconds.

**!EVERE [10:04:20 06-Nov-19 GMT][javax.baja.web.BWebServer] failed: java.net.BindException: Failed to bind to https port I 443], http port [80],or both
443], http port [80],or both
               LU  LU iiLL, pang. twin, i aay pant. Loy, Ul vv
    at** com.tridium.jetty.BlettyWebServer.doStartWebServer(BlettyWebServer.java:833)
    at javax.baja.web.BWebServer.startWebServer(BWebServer.java:237) 
    at javax.baja.web.BWebServer.doRestart(BWebServer.java:327)
    at auto.com_tridium_jetty_B]ettyWebServer.invoke(AutoGenerated)
    at com.tridium.sys.schema.ComponentSlotMap.invoke(ComponentSlotMap.java:1890)
    at com.tridium.sys.engine.EngineUtil.doInvoke(EngineUtil.java:62) 
    at javax.baja.sys.BComponent.doInvoke(BComponent.java:1258)
    at javax.baja.util.Invocation.run(Invocation.java:47)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadRoolExecutor.runWbrker(ThreadRoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadRoolExecutor$Wbrker.run(ThreadRoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

INFO [10:04:20 06-Nov-19 GMT][javax.baja.web.BWebServer] Scheduling restart in 5 seconds.
SEVERE [10:04:20 06-Nov-19 GMT][fox] FOXS server failed to bind to port [4911] java.net.BindException: Address already i 
n use 1VM_Bind
```

3. I get the error as shown in the image attached[image]

Comment: Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be read aloud or copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Comment: I dont entirely agree as the image with the screenshot of error gives quite a bit of information, although for convinience i took out the text.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can't specify the Fox port on the command line. You have to change the 'Port' property in the FoxService and then start the Station as usual.